# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' when using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am running the following code from a YouTube tutorial, but when I want to get the text from class `.totalcount`, I got the `NoneType Object has no attribute "text"` error.

In fact in the tutorial video it worked. Any help? If in details that will be awesome. Thanks in advance.

```
url = "https://newyork.craigslist.org/"
site = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(site.text, "html.parser")

sub_link = soup.select("#jjj0 a")
for l in sub_link:
    jobcat = l.text
    joburl = "https://newyork.craigslist.org/" + l.get("href")
    #print(joburl)
    r = requests.get(joburl)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    #for total in soup2.select_one("span", class_ = "totalcount"):
        #print(total)
    total = soup2.select_one(".totalcount").text
    #total  = soup2.find("span", class_ = "totalcount").text.strip()

    print(total)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running your code and un-commented the print statement for the `joburl`.

On the first iteration, it shows

```
https://newyork.craigslist.org//d/accounting-finance/search/acc
```

Notice it has a double slash after the base part `https://newyork.craigslist.org`.

Opening this up in a browser shows a 404 Not Found page.

Many webservers will (conveniently) resolve multiple slashes in URLs for you -- thereby avoiding such annoying situations that can arise. It seems that this site doesn't.

The way to resolve it is to remove the trailing slash from this line:

```
joburl = "https://newyork.craigslist.org/" + l.get("href")
```

But its better to instead remove it from where you define the base `url` atop your file.

The following works:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url = "https://newyork.craigslist.org"
site = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(site.text, "html.parser")

sub_link = soup.select("#jjj0 a")
for l in sub_link:
    jobcat = l.text
    joburl = url + l.get("href")
    # print(joburl)
    r = requests.get(joburl)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    total = soup2.select_one(".totalcount").text
    print(total)
```

Comment: Oh thank you. Yes it is working. and thank you for the detailed answer. you are great.